# Why do multiple react-renders break leaflet-draw editing, and how do I fix it?

Tags: reactjs, react-leaflet, leaflet.draw

**Workaround:**

The best workaround that I could find so far - I'll leave this open in case someone comes up with something better. Two parts:

1. Assign a 'cache-busting' key as in the update below (use UUID or something better than Math.random. This will fix the initial issue but create a new problem, which is that subsequent renders will cause errors when editing disable tries to unhook from the no longer existent geometry.
2. Fix this secondary problem by keeping track of editing mode and disabling renders for the map component by returning shouldComponentUpdate false for the duration of edit, something like this:

   ```
   shouldComponentUpdate(){
       return !isEditingGeometry();
   }
   ```

---

**Update:**

Since I posted this, I started working on the assumption that this was a DOM/React lifecycle issue. This "fixes" the problem in the stupidest possible way:

```
<Polygon key={Math.random()} positions={positions}/>
```

I'm going to leave the question open in case someone has a better idea or I come up with a more robust fix, but I'm now under the impression that this issue isn't in my code but something in one or more of the libraries, but I'm not sure how to set about fixing it, and I find it a bit perplexing that this isn't a known issue. Surely someone is using leaflet-draw in production somewhere?

---

**Question:**

I have a project where I'm attempting to use the leaflet-draw editing tools in the context of react. Below is a sample of the most basic implementation of this which mirrors what I'm doing. If you create a fresh create-react-app and replace App.js with this code you can run this and see the bug.

What happens: The map renders, the shapes render. If you click on the "edit" button, the geometries are given handles and you can adjust them. This is all fine.

If a subsequent render occurs (I fake this in the sample code by changing the state with a timer) then when you click edit, the geometries receive handles but cannot be adjusted - only the handles move. Cancelling and clicking "edit" again (before another render) allows you to edit the shapes.

This is driving me crazy - I have come across several posts that indicate there's a general problem with leaflet-draw and polygon editing after version 4.12, but locking that version doesn't seem to help the situation (I just get a bonus slew of deprecated warnings).

Is this a bug in the library or am I doing something dumb on the react side that I'm not seeing? Any ideas or even functional workarounds gratefully accepted.

```
Relevant lines from package.json: 
   "react": "^16.2.0", 
   "react-leaflet": "^1.8.0", 
   "react-leaflet-draw": "^0.18.0", 
   "leaflet": "^1.3.0", 
   "leaflet-draw": "^0.4.9",
```

```js
import React, {Component} from 'react';

import './App.css';
import {
 Map,
 Circle,
 LayersControl,
 FeatureGroup,
 Polygon,
 TileLayer
} from 'react-leaflet';
import {EditControl} from "react-leaflet-draw"

class App extends Component {

 constructor(props) {
  super(props);
  this.state={
   thing:'stuff'
  }
 }

 componentDidMount(){
  // This is a demo hack just to force a second render
  setTimeout(() => {
   this.setState({thing:'otherstuff'});
  }, 2000);
 }

 render() {
  console.log("Render...");
    
    // Building geometries like this into an array and then in return 
    // mimics what my production code is doing, but I see the same problem 
    // if I put the geometry JSX inline below 
  let positions =[[37, -109.05],[41, -109.03],[41, -102.05],[37, -102.04]];
  let tileServerURL='http://tile.stamen.com/watercolor/{z}/{x}/{y}.png';
  let editableGeometry = [];
  editableGeometry.push(<Circle key="circle" center={[37, -109.05]} radius={2000} />);
  editableGeometry.push(<Polygon key="polygon" positions={positions}/>);


  return (
   <div style={{width:'100vw',height:'100vh'}}>
   <Map ref='map' center={[37, -109.05]} zoom={13} className="ps_n3_mapComponent" style={{width:'100vw',height:'100vh'}}>
    <LayersControl position='topright'>
     <TileLayer key="tilelayer" url={tileServerURL}/>
     <FeatureGroup ref='editableFeaturegroup'>
      <EditControl/>
      {editableGeometry}
     </FeatureGroup>
    </LayersControl>
   </Map>
  </div>);
 }
}

export default App;
```

Comment: The best workaround that I could find so far - I'll leave this open in case someone comes up with something better but:

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same issues while working with React Leaflet as well. I became frustrated enough to write my own implementation of leaflet as a react component. Take a look: https://github.com/Chris502/PureLeafletMap

It still needs some to be able to accept some more configuration props, currently working on those now, but i think this is a good start.

*** Edit *** 
This is not an answer for the actual problem with react-leaflet and leaflet-draw. This is a map component that will let you load geoJSON features/draw and edit them without needing the `Edit Mode` boolean, or the `shouldComponentUpdate` logic. I will get a working example up.

Comment: Thank you for this answer. Can you please [edit] to explain *how* your component solves the problem, and a short summary of how you would use it? Please see [Is it acceptable to recommend a framework or library in an answer?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/342405/is-it-acceptable-to-recommend-a-framework-or-library-in-an-answer)

Answer (score 0):

I also had problems with getting the react-leaflet-draw to cooperate. I too became frustrated enough to implement a fork here: https://github.com/andrewdodd/react-leaflet-draw

The main frustration I had with react-leaflet-draw was that it automatically embeds a FeatureGroup inside the control, which it uses to store the shapes while you edit, but that you can't interact with or modify. This causes all sorts of problems when doing things the React way (i.e. not the DOM-oriented leaflet.js way), which is probably what you are experiencing.

Reading the code in my fork will probably convince you that it's easier to just write your own wrapper (or to copy the files from my fork into your project).

FWIW, the "example" is actually harder to read and understand than the library itself, as the example has to deal with storing state etc.

Answer (score 0):

If you use react functional component and the polygon coordinates come from props. You should use useEffect and useState and when props changes the whole component rerendering.

```
const EditPolygon = ({ coordinates }: OwnProps) => {
  const [polygonData, setPolygonData] = useState()

  useEffect(() => {
    setPolygonData(coordinates)
  }, [coordinates]) 

return (
<FeatureGroup>
  <EditControl />
<Polygon positions={coordinates} key={some.id}>
</FeatureGroup>
)
```